# Is it OK to expose admin API endpoints on frontend, as long as they're secure?

Tags: api, websites

I'm wondering if it's OK for sharing the same frontend panel with admins and normal users. Although, it would expose some *admin-accessible-only* API endpoints.

A malicious attacker would be able to inspect the page and try to find vulnerabilities on those endpoints. Which wouldn't be possible to do so, if the frontend panel wasn't shared in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"as long as they're secure" is a strong guarantee; I'm not sure how you can be sure of that but, given this condition, there shouldn't be any problem exposing admin API endpoints to other users (not the public, however).

Having said that, here are a couple of points you may want to consider:

- It is a common practice to have admin functionality alongside the non-privileged one, because the separation of the roles of an admin and a user is just a matter of permissions found in the backing store (e.g. database). This keeps things simple, because most designs of this type allow admin-specific functionality to be executed depending on the permissions of each user. This, however, has the problem that if any admin functionality is misconfigured, then it is exposed to the rest of the user set. This design is a common choice for systems that do not require advanced security measures
- If there's a need to be extra cautious about who's using the admin API, then yes, you should take extra steps to avoid having random users (or the general public) poking with it. Separate access (i.e. putting the admin API on different *security* **and** *trust* domains) and monitoring (user behaviour, traffic etc) may be needed on top of everything else. This, however, depends on what your system does and how critical the data you want to protect are

Answer (score 0):

Defense in depth says you should separate the two interfaces and put the admin interface behind a VPN.

However, if giving admins VPN access is not feasible, or the number of admins are large and they are basically just slightly more trusted users, then it probably does not make a lot of difference.